# How to compare vectors approximately in Eigen?

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen

Is there a function in Eigen to compare vectors (matrices) using both relative and absolute tolerance aka [numpy.allclose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html)? Standard [isApprox](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a710e3763df8518854578a160c1a8902d) fails if one of the vectors is very close to zero.

Comment: See http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-2.0/TutorialCore.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no built-in function implementing numpy.allclose, but you easily write one yourself if that's really what you need. However, I'd rather suggest the use of [isMuchSmallerThan](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a40b9e8df68a52b2d46cf70c9babf2a16) with reference value:

```
(a-b).isMuchSmallerThan(ref)
```

where ref is a representative non zero for your problem.

EDIT: for reference here is a possible implementation of allclose:

```
template<typename DerivedA, typename DerivedB>
bool allclose(const Eigen::DenseBase<DerivedA>& a,
              const Eigen::DenseBase<DerivedB>& b,
              const typename DerivedA::RealScalar& rtol
                  = Eigen::NumTraits<typename DerivedA::RealScalar>::dummy_precision(),
              const typename DerivedA::RealScalar& atol
                  = Eigen::NumTraits<typename DerivedA::RealScalar>::epsilon())
{
  return ((a.derived() - b.derived()).array().abs()
          <= (atol + rtol * b.derived().array().abs())).all();
}
```

Comment: isMuchSmallerThan can be used for absolute comparison, i.e. (a-b).isMuchSmallerThan(1.0, atol) is equivalent to np.allclose(a, b, 0.0, atol), so to mimic np.allclose we have to do something like this: (a-b).isMuchSmallerThan(1.0, atol) || a.isApprox(b, rtol). Am I correct?

Comment: Not exactly because isMuchSmallerThan and isApprox are based on the L2 matrix norm and not element-wise comparisons (infinite norm).

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that this, like numpy's `allclose`, is not symmetric, and `b` is expected to be a reference value.  If you need a symmetric comparison, multiply `rtol` by `a.derived().array().abs().max(b.derived().array().abs())` instead.

Comment: For Quaternions which have a `coeffs()` method to get at the matrix and where negatives are equivelent:  `auto e{ atol + rtol * b.coeffs().derived().array().abs() }; return ((a.coeffs().derived() - b.coeffs().derived()).array().abs() <= e).all() || ((a.coeffs().derived() + b.coeffs().derived()).array().abs() <= e).all();`

Answer (score 5):

There is also isApprox function which was not working for me. 
I am just using ( expect - res).norm() < some small number.